# css filter: blur frosting glass effect not working, no blur, content is influenced

Tags: html, css, background-color, blur

I want to have a background photo with a div in front.
The div should have a blurry dark background and white text.

But what it is doing at the moment is: dark background without blur and dark text.
Please help me!

```css
#section0 {
background-color: lightgreen; /*normally the photo*/
}

.blurwrapper {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.blur {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: black;
filter: blur(1px);
opacity: 0.2;
transform: scale(1.5);
z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
color: white;
}
.about {
color: white;
background: none;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
max-width: 800px;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 2px;
color: white;
border-top: 1px solid white;
z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="section active" id="section0">
    <div class="blurwrapper">
      <h1><span>...</span></h1>
      <p class="about">...</p>
      <div class="blur"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the blur filter as you can see is applied to the current element.
This means that if you want to blur the image you need to apply the blur to the `#section0` container that has the `background-image` set. If you have a colour instead of an image you will see only the border blurred.

For more information please have a look at the documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

To give a more clear example using your code: http://codepen.io/ThePeach/full/egYbbe/

Comment: So what can I do to reach my goal? I don't want to blur the whole background-image, only the party where the text goes.

Comment: then the solution is to duplicate the background in another div, and place it at the same exact position as the container, while blurring it. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: But how can I have the blurred part only behind the content and not on the whole page?

Comment: stack the elements as needed perhaps using `z-index`?